# How SQL sets the value and attributes of the same node in XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

We have this code:

```
SELECT          
    (SELECT
         'infor' AS [Process/TenantID],
         (SELECT 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY gld_serial_no ASC) as [@sequence],
              (SELECT TOP (1) 
                   '1' AS [DimensionCode/@sequence],
                   gld_dim1 AS [DimensionCode] 
               FROM 
                   slr_gl_dta_paid 
               GROUP BY 
                   gld_dim1
               FOR XML PATH ('DimensionCode'), TYPE) AS [DimensionCodes]
          FROM 
              slr_gl_dta_paid
          FOR XML PATH ('JournalEntryLine'), TYPE) AS [SourceSystemJournalEntry]
      FOR XML PATH ('DataArea'), type
  ) 
  FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry')
```

The result is like this:

```
<ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry>
    <DataArea>
        <Process>
            <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        </Process>
        <SourceSystemJournalEntry>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="1">
                <DimensionCodes>
                    <DimensionCode>
                        <DimensionCode sequence="1">CD53</DimensionCode>
                    </DimensionCode>
                </DimensionCodes>
            </JournalEntryLine>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="2">
                <DimensionCodes>
                    <DimensionCode>
                        <DimensionCode sequence="1">CD99</DimensionCode>
                    </DimensionCode>
                </DimensionCodes>
            </JournalEntryLine>
        </SourceSystemJournalEntry>
    </DataArea>
</ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry>
```

But we need the result to be like this:

```
<ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry>
    <DataArea>
        <Process>
            <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        </Process>
        <SourceSystemJournalEntry>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="1">
                <DimensionCodes>
                    <DimensionCode sequence="1">CD53</DimensionCode>
                </DimensionCodes>
            </JournalEntryLine>
            <JournalEntryLine sequence="2">
                <DimensionCodes>
                    <DimensionCode sequence="1">CD99</DimensionCode>
                </DimensionCodes>
            </JournalEntryLine>
        </SourceSystemJournalEntry>
    </DataArea>
</ProcessSourceSystemJournalEntry>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    1 AS 'DimensionCode/@sequence',
    gld_dim1 AS DimensionCode
FROM 
    gl_dta
GROUP BY   
    gld_dim1
FOR XML PATH('DimensionCodes'), ROOT('JournalEntry')
```

This should create a `<DimensionCode>` element that contains the `gld_dim1` value as element text, and a `sequence` attribute on it.

Comment: Perhaps one should note the ATTRIBUTE(s) must be presented first.

Comment: Sorry for over simplification. I updated my question.